# Drawing a right triangle in Python 3

Tags: python

Trying to draw a right triangle on Python 3. Here is the output i'm trying to achieve and the code i've written so far: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZKZ9.png)

Here is my output and error message : [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IImi3.png)

I seem to have gotten the shape correct but It seems it wants me to remove the spacing at the end of each line on the triangle. I'm not sure how I can remove the space at the end of the line while keeping the spaces between the "%" symbols?

Comment: https://www.jquery-az.com/how-to-remove-whitespaces-in-strings-of-python/

Comment: A) Please paste your code as text (with code blocks) vs image
B) I'm pretty sure you're printing without spaces at the end... are you possibly hitting an issue between windows and unix regarding whether newline == \n or \r\n?  Reason for thinking this is that if you print out: print(" ".join(x*5)+"!"), the ! is right next to the last copy of x (which is "*"), so there isn't a trailing space that I can see  (contrariwise, is it possible they _want_ whitespace at the end?